# How to interface an existing class

Tags: c++, class, dll, enums, private

I have this Class that have an enum "AT_Color" inside:

```
class K_DxfDwgColor {
enum AT_Color { Normal = 0, ByLayer = 1, ByBlock = 2 };

COLORREF m_crColor = 0;
AT_Color  m_atColor = AT_Color::Normal;

public:
    K_DxfDwgColor(COLORREF pkColorref) :m_crColor(pkColorref) {};
    K_DxfDwgColor(K_DxfDwgColor::AT_Color paColor):m_atColor(paColor){};

    OdCmColor colorClone;

    OdCmColor         SetLayerColor(bool pbDefaultForegroundColor, bool pbByLayer, bool pbIsSolidFill);
    COLORREF          GetColor(){ return m_crColor;}
    AT_Color          GetType() { return m_atColor;}
};
```

The enum is declared private in the class, which means it is not accessiblefrom the main.
Now, we want to declare an object for this class and use the constructor which gets an AT_Color.

```
K_DxfDwgColor colorDefiner(K_DxfDwgColor::ByBlock);
```

Every time I declare my object this way, I get an error message that the enum is inaccessible. Can someone show me how to declare it correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to refer to it from outside the class, it must be public.

Comment: so no chance to change it using any other method ??

Comment: The enum should be public. If it's a parameter that is received in the constructor, you must access it outside of the class

Comment: You can hide the constructor and add one static factory function for each value (e.g. `K_DxfDwgColor colorDefiner = K_DxfDwgColor::ColorByBlock();`) but that's mostly clutter without much advantage.

Comment: In my opinion that constructor and enum should be both public or private, it's a little incoherent as it is

Comment: You can make `main` a friend.

Comment: i just changed all to public. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the enum outside of the class, it is necessary to be known from the calling party:

```
enum AT_Color { Normal = 0, ByLayer = 1, ByBlock = 2 };

class K_DxfDwgColor {
public:
    K_DxfDwgColor(AT_Color paColor):m_atColor(paColor){};
}
```